# Query Firebase value inside AutoID in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if a certain `userid` is in the `usedBy` child to ensure a user cannot use it twice, but I am having trouble trying to query the `usedBy` child since it is entered by AutoID

I have something like this in Swift, but does not accomplish what I need, but do now know how to query it correctly:

```
promoCodes.child(code).child("usedBy").queryEqual(toValue: userid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Realtime Database queries always consist of two parts:

1. First you order the data on either the key, the (single, atomic) value, or on the value of a property.
2. Then you filter the data based on those value.

You're missing the first part in your query, which would be:

```
promoCodes.child(code).child("usedBy").queryOrdered(byChild:"userid").queryEqual(toValue: userid).
```